# SQL Server CPU Permanently stuck at 100%

Tags: sql-server, cpu-usage

For months we have been plagued with an issue where a database which serves two web servers has its CPU shoot up to 100% and stay there, for hours if we let it.  All 6 processors.  This happens every few days at different times of the day.  The CPU usage is due to the sqlserver.exe.

This is **not** a general SQL Server performance issue ("how do I make my queries more efficient"). When there is an incident, CPU goes from its typical 20% up to 100% and stays there until a server reboot.

We are on SQL Server 2016 SP2 cumulative update 6.

We've added some logging and see that during the latest CPU incident, the number of spinlocks on OPT_IDX_STATS shot up to 5775813 spins per collision.  Not sure if that's the cause or a symptom?

```
Before CPU 100% incident

name                      collisions      spins spins_per_collision sleep_time backoffs
----                      ----------      ----- ------------------- ---------- --------
OPT_IDX_STATS                    787     200250            254.4473          0        5
LOCK_HASH                    2137398  630970500             295.205       1410    52938

1 minute later

name              collisions    spins spins_per_collision sleep_time backoffs
----              ----------    ----- ------------------- ---------- --------
OPT_IDX_STATS             12 69309750             5775813          7       27
LOCK_HASH              17292 49187101              2844.5         47      555
```

We see around 40 queries running when an incident hints.  They are typically instances of the same two LINQ queries.  No query ever has an elapsedMS of longer than 20,000ms, so it's not a long running query that's crushing the CPU.  They are expensive queries, but it seems to be a symptom of the problem not a cause - we see those queries piling up because the DB is running so slow because CPU is so high.  Those same queries (along with others) are being executed all the time, including after the DB server is rebooted, and they don't cause a problem after a reboot.

The server has 36 GB of memory and we don't see usage going higher than 22%.

Some other interesting information, killing the currently running queries lets the CPU drop, but only briefly (shoots up again as the web servers send more queries).  Pausing the DB to let the queries finish lets the CPU drop for as long as it's paused, but then it shoots up when the DB is resumed.  Rebooting the database server **always** fixes the issue.  Before and after the database reboot the webservers should be sending the same types of queries, which points to a problem with SQL Server - otherwise why would a reboot fix the problem?

*Update: I wrote a PowerShell script that clears the plan cache if the CPU is > 95% for 45 seconds and that seems to have worked around the problem.  Still don't know what the issue is though.*

Comment: TrustedInstaller.  It's always Windows Update trying do do something ... well for me at least.

Comment: Can you correlate the CPU usage with cpu_time request in sys.dm_exec_requests, or a session in sys.dm_exec_sessions?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I added some more information (second to last paragraph) about the currenly running queries.

Comment: What is the memory configuration for the SQL Server? Do you have it set to correctly limit the amount of memory SQL Server will try to claim for itself? I've seen people leave it at the default, and then get into pathological situations where SQL Server claims more memory than is available, causing it and the OS to swap, cratering performance. This is always the first thing to check.

Comment: The next thing to check is your plan caches and the like. If you have hard-coded SQL queries (not parameterized) that vary with requests, you could have a horribly polluted plan cache. Try turning the "Optimze for ad-hoc queries" option on under Advanced options. Try clearing all caches and see if that affects performance (something short of a reboot).

Comment: @pmbAustin Thanks.  This server has 36 GB of memory and we don't see usage going higher than 22%.

Comment: @pmbAustin The queries are generated by LINQ so they are all parameterized.

Comment: Maybe post the Linq query? Or ideally, the captured SQL that it ends up executing via profiler... otherwise we are just guessing

Comment: @Milney I really don't think it *is* the LINQ queries because they are executed all the time, including after a DB server reboot (at which point they cause no problems).  I think maybe it's a low level SQL Server issue?  The SQL for the queries is so long it gets cropped but here it is: https://pastebin.com/eePJY4E9

Comment: If you can, I recommend using Brent Ozar's BlitzFirst tool just to weed out any really easy answers. https://www.brentozar.com/askbrent/

Comment: Also, can you provide any information about the level of concurrency going on with these connections/queries? Do you have any kind of connection pooling? How many concurrent connections are allowed? Do connections on the web server time out after a certain amount of time, or are they allowed to just build up forever? Will your web servers revert to returning 503s rather than accepting more requests once they have enough requests queued, or will the servers just keep accepting more requests and issuing more queries?

Comment: Ok.  Turn on Query Store, and see if there is a difference in query execution cost for specific queries between when the problem is happening and when it's not.  And there _is_ a different query plan causing the issue, Query Store will allow you to force the good plan(s).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @mhenry1384 - I mean, SQL doesn't just use CPU for no reason, so it MUST be in same way related to the queries. Perhaps you have a deadlock that is compounding

Comment: @mhenry1384 - Are there inserts being run? Do the tables have Identity columns? Depending on the isolation level you have SQL set at - they may be interleaving reading the ID and inserting rows which can build up locks like this

Comment: @pmbAustin I wrote a PowerShell script that clears the plan cache if the CPU is > 95% for 45 seconds and that seems to have worked around the problem.  I still don't know what the issue is, but if you put checking/clearing the plan cache as an answer I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Copying comments to an answer as requested:

What is the memory configuration for the SQL Server? Do you have it set to correctly limit the amount of memory SQL Server will try to claim for itself? I've seen people leave it at the default, and then get into pathological situations where SQL Server claims more memory than is available, causing it and the OS to swap, cratering performance. This is always the first thing to check. There are guides out there for the best value for this particular setting for your memory, OS, and configuration. A good rule of thumb for 80% of normal configurations is take installed memory, subtract 4GB, and use that value for SQL Server.

The next thing to check is your plan caches and the like. If you have hard-coded SQL queries (not parameterized) that vary with requests, you could have a horribly polluted plan cache. Try turning the "Optimize for ad-hoc queries" option on under Advanced options. Try clearing all caches and see if that affects performance (something short of a reboot).

Answer (score 0):

You can look at using Resource Governor, I've had to do it in a similar situation where I HAD to share the database with some resource hogs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/resource-governor/resource-governor?view=sql-server-2017

It's still relevant in SQL 2016 but I didn't easily find the link.